# MIPS actual encoding scheme

Tags: search, mips, hashtable, opcode

How does MIPS actually store opcodes against instructions? Does it linearly search or use hashtable?

I want to know how does it do either in digital logic terms or programming terms.

What i mean is how does "add" become 0x10. Does it perform operation on the ascii code of "add" or it has it already saved and if saved then how?

If not for MIPS then any other architecture would work.

What i have found till now is it that it forms a symbol table for these opcodes. Any links for this would be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The processor doesn't execute assembly code; it executes machine code, and therefore never sees the text mnemonics (`add`, `lw`, `or`, etc). The conversion is done by the assembler.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but that is what I wanted to ask how does the assembler go about it? Has it already stored, does it save the whole green sheet or make the ascii hashed in such a way that it becomes the opcode? That is what I am asking.

Comment: That probably depends mostly on who coded the assembler. It's just a program, after all.

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael noted in his comment, the processor never sees your mnemonic (such as `add` or `lw`). In fact, some of the most common command mnemonics (such as `bge`, branch if greater than or equal) are actually pseudo-instructions, which the compiler converts into multiple native instructions.

If you Google "MIPS Green Sheet", you'll find the reference card that is included in the typical Computer Architecture textbook, explaining how each instruction line - mnemonic plus parameters - is converted to a 32-bit word.

If you spend some time plugging MIPS instructions into the [MIPS Instruction Converter](http://www.mipshelper.com/mips-converter.php%20MIPS%20Instruction%20Converter), you'll see how something like `add $t0, $t1, $t2` becomes a 32-bit sequence of 1's and 0's (represented in hex as `0x012A4020`), which is all the CPU ever really sees.